# No Heads-Up / Sound when firing Notification on API 25 or lower

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

When using the [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat) on Android, the notifications only work as expected on API level 26 or higher.

- I want: A notification with Heads-Up message + sound on every possible API level (21+).
- I did: Setup a NotificationChannel, set the channel importance and notification priority, as described in the [notification docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)
- I get: A notification with Heads-Up + sound on API Level 26+ and a notification **without** Heads-Up and **without** sound on API Level 25 or less

Code:

```
val chan2 = NotificationChannel(SECONDARY_CHANNEL,
    getString(R.string.noti_channel_second), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
manager.createNotificationChannel(chan2)

fun getNotification2(title: String, body: String): NotificationCompat.Builder {
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, SECONDARY_CHANNEL)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
}

fun notifySecondaryChannel(id: Int, notification: NotificationCompat.Builder) {
    notification.priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
    manager.notify(id, notification.build())
}
```

Dependencies:

- support lib version:  27.1.1
- compile / target sdk: 27
- gradle tools: 3.1.3

Full code [on github](https://github.com/C0d3GGz/android-NotificationChannels/tree/master/kotlinApp) (forked and updated google sample).

Comment: Have you tried builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) or builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: @Elletlar Yes I did! Both `DEFAULT_SOUND` and `DEFAULT_ALL` work! Why is the `setDefaults` call needed? I cannot find anything within the docs about this being mandatory. 
Thank you so much (will accept your answer when present)

Comment: Not sure: setDefaults has always been a standard practise. It would be good to know why that behaviour has changed for newer devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sound can be played by using:

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) or 
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
```

or one of the overrides of setSound. For exmaple:

```
public Notification.Builder setSound (Uri sound, 
                int streamType)
```